# I have got cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile error on using strstr() and strncopy functions

Tags: c, arrays, string, function

one of my exam questions is about changing a word in a sentence. Well i decided to learn and implement string functions to get a better use but i'm stuck somewhere.

Basically, the code works if it's in main like here

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="lazyness is a sure thing";
  char w1[]="sure";
  char w2[]="lame";


  char *pch;
  pch = strstr (str,w1);
  strncpy (pch,w2,strlen(w1));
  puts (str);
  return 0;
}
```

But i can not make it work in a void function which i need to run in exam.

And the code i need follows;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


// == CHANGE STARTS BELOW THIS LINE ==

void replace(char sentence[],char w1[],char w2[]){


    char *pch;
    pch = strstr (sentence,w1);
   strncpy (pch,w2,strlen(w1));

}


// == CHANGE STOPS ABOVE THIS LINE ==

void readString(char str[])
{
    char ch;
    scanf("%c", &ch);
    int i = 0;
    while(ch != '\n')
{
    str[i] = ch;
    scanf("%c", &ch);
    i++;
}
str[i] = '\0';
}

int main(void) {

char sentence[101];
char word1[21];
char word2[21];

readString(sentence);
readString(word1);
readString(word2);

replace(sentence, word1, word2);

printf("%s", sentence);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

}

You can only change between change starts this line and change stops above this line because the others parts must stay still to exam program can read it.

Please help, thanx a lot :)

Comment: Also both of the words are checked same length.

Comment: I directly made null the last element still didn't work out. I enter the words with same length. If you can, please fix the code. Else {finals are gonna kill me;} :D